# JSP is not displayed after very long controller call

Tags: java, spring

**Situation:** 
I have a Java (Spring) web application, where a user can upload a file. This file will then be analyzed and the results are presented to the user on a new JSP.
The simplified controller method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String fileUploaded(Model model, File file, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    /** Do very long calculations. */
    model.addAttribute("map", /** very large map */);
    return "result_page";
}
```

**Problem:** 
The code works fine on my local Netbeans/Tomcat configuration. But on the server (after deploying the *.war), the application does not work for large files. The program runs till the `return "result_page";` statement and then the page is not displayed. Without any error in the tomcat Log (`catalina.out`). The previous upload-JSP remains present. Note, that the large files are working on my local Tomcat.

**Tried Solutions:** 
I thought the problem could be the session-timeout. On my local config, the large files took 20 minutes until the `return` is reached. On the server, it takes 40 minutes. Thus, the default 30 minutes timeout could be an issue. I tried to change the timeout in the `web.xml`. But setting the session-timeout to 120 minutes did not solve the issue. Also setting the timeout to 1 minute didn't reproduce the error on my local configuration.

**Question:** 
What am I missing? Is it the timeout I just configured wrong, or what could be the reason? Are there other Log-Files I can search for Error-Messages?

Comment: Can you post your server.xml config file and also web.xml or equivalent class where you are specifying  multi-part length limit

Comment: do you know what is slower? if the time to process the file or to render it in the JSP?

Comment: as cralfaro says, i think it takes too long to render the jsp and also too long to download it to the client browser, you may have to wait longer, you may want to use Network tab in Chrome browser's Developers tool, you can see what's going on (network wise) you may wait longer and see the result, also if you wait longer you may have a connection-timeout

Comment: @cralfaro the 20 minutes difference results from the processing time. The RAM and the CPU is slower on the server.

Comment: My question was focus because you could use websockets, so you upload the file, inmediatelly returns a jsp page, with a message of file in process, then open a websocket and when the job is done render the result in the page. Then you only need to worry about improve the file processing time